# Nested commands with commander

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-commander

I have the following code

```
export const program = new Command();

program.version('0.0.1');

program
  .command('groups')
  .command('create')
  .action(() => console.log('creating'))
  .command('delete')
  .action(() => console.log('deleting-all'))

program.parse(process.argv)
```

What I want to achieve is something like

`groups create` and `groups delete`

The code however chains that delete to the create. It recognizes `groups create` and `groups create delete` (which I dont want) but does not recognize the `groups delete`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to add the `delete` subcommand to the `groups` command. e.g.

```js
const { Command } = require('commander');

const program = new Command();

program.version('0.0.1');

const groups = program
  .command('groups');
groups
  .command('create')
  .action(() => console.log('creating'))
groups
  .command('delete')
  .action(() => console.log('deleting-all'))

program.parse(process.argv)
```

The related example file is: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/master/examples/nestedCommands.js

Comment: Can you add deeply nested commands? Like `foo groups something other create`?

Comment: Yes. Just add each new subcommand to the previous command and build up a chain.